# Remove brackets [] from a list set to a textview?

Tags: java, android

I am parsing content using the following code with jsoup.

```
  try{
 Elements divElements = jsDoc.getElementsByTag("div");
 for(Element divElement : divElements){
     if(divElement.attr("class").equals("article-content")){
         textList.add(divElement.text());
         text = textList.toString();
     }
 }
}
catch(Exception e){

System.out.println("Couldnt get content");
       }
```

The only problem is the content is returned with brackets around it [] like that.

Im guessing it is becaue of the list i am setting it to. How can i remove these?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Replace:

```
text = textList.toString();
```

with:

```
text = textList.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
```

Comment: it won't work if there are brackets in the real contents of textList

Comment: I guess the question clearly asked that user needs to remove the brackets from array.toString() output and your solution will replace all the "[" and "]" accross the converted string even if it will be the part of real content

Answer (score 8):

Using regex to replace the leading and trailing brackets, String.replace() doesn't work for the edge cases that the list's content contains brackets.

```
String text = textList.toString().replaceAll("(^\\[|\\]$)", "");
```

Comment: RIGHT ANSWER indeed!

Comment: This seems like it should be right... but it does not work for me

Answer (score 2):

Yes, its because of the List. You have to Options:
Subclass whatever TextList is, and override toString()
or

```
String temp = textList.toString();
text = temp.subString(1, temp.size() -2);
```

Answer (score 1):

For most objects, the `toString()` method is not intended to be used for display, but usually debugging.  This is because the `toString()` method generally doesn't have a specific format and could vary depending on the particular class used.  For example, a LinkedList and ArrayList could return different values from `toString()`.  It's unlikely, but its something you should avoid relying on.  Of course, if the object represents actual text (`String`, `StringBuilder`, `CharSequence`), the above doesn't apply.

Also, you are creating and assigning the string multiple times in the for loop.  Instead, you should only create the string after the for loop is done.

To create the string you can roll your own or use a library like [Apache commons lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/), which has a `StringUtils.join()` utility method.

If you roll your own, it might look something like this:

```
Elements divElements = jsDoc.getElementsByTag("div");
Iterator<Element> iterator = divElements.iterator();
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

while (iterator.hasNext()){
   Element divElement = iterator.next()
   if (divElement.attr("class").equals("article-content")){
      builder.append(divElement.text());
      if (iterator.hasNext()) {
         builder.append(", ");
      }
   }
}
text = builder.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement your own method to create the `String` you need using iteration and `StringBuffer`. It is not a good practice to `replace` parentheses or `substring` such output.

Answer (score 0):

You may override toString() method.

Set example:

```
class SetPrinter<E> extends HashSet<E> {

    public SetPrinter(Set<E> set) {
        super(set);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        Iterator<E> i = iterator();
        if (!i.hasNext()) {
            return "";
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (; ; ) {
            E e = i.next();
            sb.append(e == this ? "(this Collection)" : e);
            if (!i.hasNext())
                return sb.toString();
            sb.append(",");
        }
    }
}
```

Use:

new SetPrinter(SetToPrint).toString();

Answer (score 0):

Simply use like this. It is working for me.

```
Text(text.toString().replaceAll('[', "").replaceAll(']', ''));
```